# Editing RTF and preserving tags?

Tags: editor, document, rtf

I have a templates written in RTF (with some tags which are replaced by data from DB in app), but when I edit them in MS Word, Word put some invisible tags to the templates, which destruct my tags (I must open template in Notepad and edit code).

Do you know some editor for RTF, which strict follows RTF specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know that google find bunch of editors, but I don`t have time to try each of them to find out best one.

so I search for advice which is good, not which is avialable

EDIT: I found and for weeks use this solution

[TE EDIT](http://www.subsystems.com/tewf.htm)

and is very good, I recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, the included app Wordpad is pretty decent in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The RTF spec allows an RTF editor such as Word or a third party control to sprinkle the tags in-between the RTF text, provided that the actually RTF display is maintained. For this reason, there is no way to guarantee that your original template text will not be disturbed. For this reason, I recommend using an RTF editor API to do any search/replacement within your template.  The RTF editor knows to put aside the RTF tags and access the original text as intended.